# Can a string returned from a .Net web service be null?

Tags: .net, web-services, null, asmx

I have a generated stub for a .net web service which has several string properties. Given some response from the web service, can these properties have a null value or are they always at least converted to a string.Empty?

Are they only possibly null if the 'nillable="true"' attribute is applied to them in the WSDL?

You see... I want to just start Trim()'ing the values of the properties without getting any null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server should serialize a null value as null, not String.Empty, unless there's some additional logic put in place. If you don't wanna write a bunch of null checks, consider making an extension method for trim.

```
public static string TrimOrEmpty(this string val)
{
    if (val == null) { return string.Empty; }
    return val.Trim();
}
```

Edit: Or go with Anders' more streamlined version. :)

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer from Anders to yours because I realised I didn't like the idea of calling Trim() on a string that I knew was empty!

Answer (score 2):

They can be null. If you use an extension method, you can gracefully handle the `null` case:

```
public static string SafeTrim(this string source)
{
  return (source ?? string.Empty).Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be null.

It might be null if the tag was not present.

Comment: So what's the point of the tag? I'd have thought the tag would need to be present to allow a null.

Comment: Generally, in an XML context, if the tag is present, the innerXML will be the value of the string. If the tag is not present, the result will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  strings from a web service can have a null value if the WSDL includes the `'nillable=true'` attribute for the field.